Understanding the consequences of Hilbert Nullstellensatz
So I was reading Fulton's Algebraic Curves and was stuck in Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, specifically, its direct consequences (see photo).
Corollary 1-3

Corollary 1. If $I$ is a radical ideal in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$, then $I(V(I)) = I$. So there is a one-to-one correspondence between radical
ideals and algebraic sets.
Corollary 2. If $I$ is a prime ideal, then $V(I)$ is irreducible. There is a one-to-one correspondence between prime ideals and
irreducible algebraic sets. The maximal ideals correspond to points.
Corollary 3. Let $F$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$, $F = F_1^{n_1} F_2^{n_2} ... F_r^{n_r}$ the decomposition of $F$ into irreducible
factors. Then $V(F) = V(F_1) \cup \cdots \cup V(F_r)$ is the decomposition of
$V(F)$ into irreducible components, and $I(V(F)) = (F_1 \cdots F_r)$. There is a one-to-one correspondence between irreducible polynomials $F\in k[X_1, ..., X_n]$ (up to multiplication by a nonzero element of $k$) and irreducible hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$.

Corollary 1 is easy to verify. But I have a hard time verifying Corollary 2 and 3. For Corollary 2, I was considering on using Fulton's proposition 1: An algebraic set V is irreducible if and only if I(V ) is prime. But I am not so sure. Can someone enlighten me?

You shouldn't use images to explain key parts of your question. Reasons for that are listed in this thread.

Which parts of the corollaries are causing you difficulty? It seems like the proposition you mention proves everything but the last statement in Corollary 2.

Corollary 3 is not correct as written, you have to assume that $F$ has no repeated factors (ie $F_i\neq F_j$ for $i\neq j$).

@ViktorVaughn Prop. 1 states that V is irreducible if and only if I(V) is prime. By applying it to Cor. 1, then V(I) is irreducible if and only if I(V(I)) is prime. But I am uncertain of this one. If this one is true then it would be easy to continue. Btw, thanks for editing!

@red_trumpet Sorry, that's my fault, or rather the fault of the automated system I used to convert the image to $\LaTeX$.

@Skye Prime ideals are radical, so $I = \sqrt{I} = \mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$.

Showing that $\mathbb{I}(a)$ is maximal when $a \in k^n$ is pretty short.
Proof.
We have that $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n) \subseteq \mathbb{I}(a)$, so we just need to prove that $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ is maximal. Under the quotient map $$ k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$$ we have $p(x) \mapsto p(a) \in k$, so $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n) \cong k$, a field. Thus, $\mathbb{I}(a)$ is maximal.
In the case where the field $|k| > \aleph_0$, we can prove pretty easily that every maximal ideal is of the form $\mathbb{I}(a)$ for some point $a \in k^n$.
Proof.
Let $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a maximal ideal, and let $F = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$. We know that $k \subseteq F$, as $k \cap I = \{0\}$. As such, either $F=k$ or $F/k$ is transcendental. If $F=k$, then $I = \mathbb{I}(a) = \mathbb{I}((a_1,\dots,a_n ))$, where we take $x_i \mapsto a_i$. If $F/k$ is transcendental, note that $\dim_k F $ is at most countable, since $\dim_k k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is countable, using the fact that quotients are vector space homomorphisms. Now, if $t \in F$ is transcendental over $k$, then $\{1/(t-a) : a \in k\}$ is an uncountable, linearly independent set, a contradiction.
Hence, maximal ideals in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ correspond to points in $k^n$.

We also have a bijection between points in any variety $V$ and maximal ideals in the coordinate ring $k[V]$. This correspondence is easy to show via the (4th?) ring isomorphism theorem bijection between ideals in $R$ containing $I$ and ideals in $R/I$.
